# Retrieve image resource using string variable in foreach loop

Tags: c#, resources, foreach

I have a string array "abc"
I put this in a for each loop. I want to retrieve an image from resources using the value in the foreach loop and put it into a picture box.

code below:

```
char[] stringArr = inputted.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char i in stringArr)
        {
            PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox(); 
            object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject(i.ToString());
            pictureBox.Image = ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
            Controls.Add(pictureBox);
        }
```

What do i have to do to get this working?
What i am trying to achieve, is a have pictures, each character in the alphabet represents a different picture, the user inputs a string and clicks a button, the users inputs is taken, formed to the stringArr and i want it to output the relevant images based on the string he inputted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("MyResourceName", resourceCulture);
return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
```

To get a resource by name.

With `ResourceManager` being something like:

```
var ResourceManager = 
    new System.Resources.ResourceManager(
        "YourAssembly.Properties.Resources", 
        typeof(Resources).Assembly);
```

So in your example you could write:

```
foreach (char i in stringArr)
{
    PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();

    object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject(i.ToString(), resourceCulture);
    pictureBox.Image = ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
}
```

(You also could omit the `resourceCulture` parameter if your image is of no special culture).

I do assume that your code is just an excerpt from a larger example since it makes no sense to me to create a `PictureBox` inside a look and *not* assign it to a form.

Comment: so in the last bit of your answer, did you mean to write i.ToString(), otherwise where are you using i

Comment: ~Well what i am trying to achieve, is a have pictures, each character in the alphabet represents a different picture, the user inputs a string and clicks a button, the users inputs is taken, formed to the stringArr and i want it to output the relevant images based on the string he inputted.

Comment: What is resourceCulture?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method you can use

Add to your code and replace XXXAPPNAMEXXX with the name of you application.

```
    public Bitmap GetImageResourceByName(string name)
    {
        Bitmap MethodResult = null;
        try
        {
            MethodResult = (Bitmap)XXXAPPNAMEXXX.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(name, XXXAPPNAMEXXX.Properties.Resources.resourceCulture);

        }
        catch //(Exception ex)
        {
            //ex.HandleException();
        }
        return MethodResult;
    }
```

Note: Go into Resources.Designer.cs and make the private attribute resourceCulture public.

I have commented out my error handling (ex.HandleException) as yours may differ.