# Retrieve image resource where the resource name is a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a self-hosted web api console app. It includes a linked resource image that I can access as:

Bitmap imgBitmap = Properties.Resources.img2

However I want to access it as variable. I.e. the name of the resource will be provided as a variable containing the string: "img2"

There are other questions on this issue, but they dont seem to work or have enough information for me to figure out how to do it. E.g.:

[Retrieve image resource using string variable in foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671302/retrieve-image-resource-using-string-variable-in-foreach-loop)

So I tried (but I am unsure exactly how to specify this - I have tried several variations) ...

```
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(
            "Properties.Resources",
            typeof(Properties.Resources).Assembly);

        var v1 = rm.GetObject("img2");
```

And that gave me the run time error...

"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Properties.Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "OwinWebApi2" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."

My Resources.Designer.cs looks like this...

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18408
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Owin_Test1.Properties {
    using System;


    /// <summary>
    ///   A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
    /// </summary>
    // This class was auto-generated by the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder
    // class via a tool like ResGen or Visual Studio.
    // To add or remove a member, edit your .ResX file then rerun ResGen
    // with the /str option, or rebuild your VS project.
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    internal class Resources {

        private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;

        private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;

        [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
        internal Resources() {
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Owin_Test1.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Overrides the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for all
        ///   resource lookups using this strongly typed resource class.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        internal static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
            get {
                return resourceCulture;
            }
            set {
                resourceCulture = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Looks up a localized resource of type System.Drawing.Bitmap.
        /// </summary>
        internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap img2 {
            get {
                object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("img2", resourceCulture);
                return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Looks up a localized string similar to &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
        ///
        ///&lt;html lang=&quot;en&quot; xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot;&gt;
        ///&lt;head&gt;
        ///    &lt;meta charset=&quot;utf-8&quot; /&gt;
        ///    &lt;title&gt;&lt;/title&gt;
        ///&lt;/head&gt;
        ///&lt;body&gt;
        ///    Page1, now in resource editor
        ///&lt;/body&gt;
        ///&lt;/html&gt;.
        /// </summary>
        internal static string Page1 {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("Page1", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the full namespace when creating the resource manager. Rather than

```
new ResourceManager(
    "Properties.Resources",
    typeof(Properties.Resources).Assembly);
```

it should be

```
new ResourceManager(
    "Owin_Test1.Properties.Resources",
    typeof(Properties.Resources).Assembly);
```

You can see that if you look at the `ResourceManager` property of `Properties.Resources`.